# Wild visual glitches and broken controls

Tags: 3d-view

Wild visual glitches and broken controls

My viewport when in solid view isn't rendering any mesh and most of my controls are broken, for example, I can't move around at all, and I have to press command + right-click to select anything.

[image]

And when I get close to the mesh it renders really weirdly, however my controls do return to normal.

[image]

Everything also returns to normal in the side or top-down views (I don't know what they are called sorry) and when I am looking through the camera.

The same weirdness applies to the other viewport shading issues, though each is slightly different.

I'm running blender 2.93.2, on an M1 mac, (which is what I originally thought was the issue but the problems occur running native Apple silicone or not, and it only happens with this blender file, every other one is fine) so if anyone has had this issue or knows how to solve this, please let me know.

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: @Chris https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XwI-NwtLdq2mG1dmT4tLMz3KoCZovUaJ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

press on this button

[image]

and then the glitches go away and you can select again.

But...don't ask me why and don't ask me what's wrong. Hopefully some Pro can help here... ;)

I assume something is wrong with your file. Looks like Blender saved there some !"&/§%/!%"§. What you can do is, start a new Blender file and use File->Append-> then choose your file and append all the stuff you need. That worked for me. No glitches. You can select everything.

Comment: Thanks! For now, I'm just going to use the append thing.